# Rails 4: Create JSON array in array inside input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby

For now, i have this inside my form:

```
<%= f.input :document, collection: @documents, wrapper: false, label: false, input_html: {class: 'fleft mleft5'} %>
```

which will production in json array:

```
[{
  "document":"126"
}]
```

**My Controller** under `create` method:

```
document: params[:ng_geofence][:document]
```

**My Model**

```
def as_hash(format=:google)
  {
    document: document
  }
end

%w[document].each do |key|
  define_method(key) do
    value && JSON.parse(value)[key]
  end
end
```

my question is how to get the output for something like this:

```
[{
  "document":
  {
    "id":"126"
  }
}]
```

**---- UPDATED ----**

If i changed my form to:

```
<%= select_tag "ng_geofence[driver_notification][document][id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@documents, "id", "name"), include_blank: true %>
```

I get this error: `757: unexpected token at '{"document"=>{"id"=>"126"}}'`

Probably because of `"=>"` instead of `":"`

Comment: Is `document` a model? because if yes, then I think I have a simpler solution.

Comment: `{ "document":"126" }` not an array, `[ .. ]` here is array, `{ .. }` whats a json object.

Comment: @Finks nope. its attr

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem. Here what i did:

**My Controller** under create method:

```
document: {
  id: params[:ng_geofence][:document]
}
```

**My Model**

```
def as_hash(format=:google)
{
  document: { id: document }
}
```